# What's this last device in AirPort Utility's Wireless Clients list?

Tags: airport

I can match all other devices to my physical devices. But I don't know what the last one is. It doesn't even have a name, only a hardware address.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an Apple Watch?

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I did forget my wife's watch. But I checked its Wi-Fi address. It's different.

Comment: (For the record: the prefix D4:9A of the hardware address indicates that the device is made by Apple according to Wireshark's manufacturer database.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I don't think that there is a definitive way to tell what is on your Wi-Fi connection, at least not without additional software (if such software exists). That said, here's what I would do to rule out products that I or my family own:

The MAC address pictured looked similar to my Apple Watch, with an Apple Watch very easily overlooked on a network. Like I said in the comments, it could be an Apple Watch, to test it just put the Apple Watch in Airplane Mode

[image]

and see if that mysterious MAC address disappears. **Even if that's not it, you can test every device in your house this way.**

Comment: Do you know how to refresh the Wireless Clients list in AirPort Utility without restarting AirPort? I turned off both the watch and the pairing iPhone but the list doesn't change.

Comment: Is that AirPort Utility 5?

Comment: It is AirPort Utility 6.3.6

Comment: Maybe it's because I have a little newer AirPort Time Capsule, but the UI is different (and I have 6.3.6). Anyway, I was able to refresh the list by clicking out of the popover and then back on the image of my router. You could probably also close AirPort Utility and reopen it, as well. By the way, disconnecting the iPhone won't disconnect the Apple Watch paired to it, as the Watch can connect to Wi-Fi on its own.

Comment: I've powered off both watch and iPhone. After several minutes the iPhone disappeared form the list but the mysterious device is still there. Besides, as I said in comment under the question, the MAC address of my watch is not the same as the Hardware address in the list. So it is not the watch.